# It is strange for her to understand the situation

Tags: grammar

1. It is strange for her to understand the situation.
   1-2. The situation is strange for her to understand.
   [Are both grammatical and the same? Do we have to use 'for' or 'of'?]

---

2. It is strange of her to understand the situation.
   2-2. She is strange to understand the situation.
   [Are both grammatical and the same? Can we use 'of' here?]

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean. What is strange? Is it the fact that she understood the situation (and that you expected her to fail to understand it)? Then your first sentence under 1 is correct:

It is strange for her to understand the situation.

Your sentence 2-2 is utterly wrong. Your first sentence under 2 seems strange to me. You'd use that construction with "of" if the adjective before the "of" were describing the person herself, e.g.

It is considerate of her to take the time to learn about the situation.

But it seems strange to me to use "strange" in that way.